# Perl module Test::MockModule and caller

Tags: perl, mocking

I'm looking for a way to test a subroutine by mocking a subroutine it calls, using the perl module `Test::MockModule`.

Let's say we test a sub `My::Module::A()`.  It calls the sub `My::New::B()`. In order to test `My::Module::A()`, I mock `My::New::B()`. `My::New::B()`, however, calls another sub `My::Calc::C()` to do some calculations. Its obligatory to call `My::Calc::C()` in the mocked sub.

```
    my $module = Test::MockModule->new('My::New');
    $module->mock( B => sub($$) 
    {
        my ($first, $second) = @_;

        My::Calc::C();
    } );
```

`My::Calc::C()` needs to know who calls it, however as a caller it receives `'main::test'` instead of `'My::New::B'`. Is there a way to tell to `My::Calc::C()` that it's called by the mocked `My::New::B()` and not by `main::test()`?

Answer (score 1):

The `package` keyword sets the current calling package. You can enclose it in braces to restrict it to a particular scope:

```
my $module = Test::MockModule->new('My::New');
    $module->mock( B => sub($$) 
    {
        my ($first, $second) = @_;

        {
            package My::New::B;
            My::Calc::C();
        }
    } );
```

Comment: That is not a solution to my problem. Perhaps you intended to write that the package name would be `“My::New”`, since `“My::New::B”` is a subroutine. Either way in your suggestion `My::Calc::C()` is called in an anonymous function and, as it is to be expected, the caller of `My::Calc::C()` isn't determined properly.